# A localidade no Jasperreport

Tags: jasper-reports

Crie um relatório no JasperSoft 6.19.1, passo a localidade (Locale) via parâmetro pelo código:

```
parameters.put(JRParameter.REPORT_LOCALE, new Locale("pt", "BR"));
JasperPrint jasperPrint = fill(beanCollection, parameters, fileName, subreportNames);
        return JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(jasperPrint);
```

Só que não funciona, o relatório sempre pega a localidade atual do sistema.

Fiz dessa forma:

```
java.text.NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new java.util.Locale("pt", "BR")).format($F{amount})
```

Mas queria fazer passando via parâmetro!

Comment: Consegui resolver depois que entendi que o jasper ignora a formatação em string, e como estava passando a formatação direto no field na expression dessa forma: new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00").format($V{interest1}.doubleValue()) o campo se transformava em String e portanto sera ignorado.
**Solução**
Passa o formato ###0.00 em TextField -> Advance -> TextField Properties -> Pattern após passar, basta passar o Locale por parametro dessa forma parameters.put(JRParameter.REPORT_LOCALE, new Locale("pt", "BR"));

Answer (score -1):

Use desta forma que vai funcionar.

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("SUBREPORT_DIR",  new ClassPathResource(String.format("/target/classes/jasper/%s.jasper", subReport)));
```

No seu jrxml deve ter um parametro chamado SUBREPORT_DIR;